# How to write search views in odoo v8?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I have been trying to write search view for a class which has inherited from other class and I have tried writing the search view for it and also added a filter to it. But I am slightly confused on how to get things together.

The following is the sequence of code:

This is the class I have used for the search view

```
class mom_ac(osv.osv):
    _name='mom.ac'
    _inherit='mom.action'
    _columns = {
        'new_field':fields.char('Action'),
    }
```

and the corresponding search view for the above class along with filter

```
<record id="minutes_meeting_search_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">mom.ac</field>
    <field name="model">mom.ac</field>
    <field eval="10" name="priority"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="MoM">
            <filter icon="terp-mail-message-new" string="Action Items" name="my_requests_filter" domain="[('Status','!=','Done')]" />
            <field name="act_ion"/>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

The following is the class from which it has been inherited

```
class mom_action(osv.Model):
    _name = 'mom.action'
    _columns = { 
        'act_ion' : fields.char('Action'),
        'meeting_id' : fields.many2one('mom.meeting','Meeting Id'),
        'asgnd_to': fields.many2one('res.users','Assigned To'),
        'due_date': fields.date('Due Date'),
        'Status'  : fields.selection([
                                    ('Yet to Start','Yet To Start'),
                                    ('In Progress', 'In Progress'),
                                    ('Done', 'Done'),
                    ], 'Status', readonly= False, select=True, default='Yet to Start'),
    }

mom_action()
```

When I click on my filter, it does not display list view with results and also when I try with Advanced Search provided by Search view, results are not shown.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only inherit you must use only `_inherit` in your inherited model. Remove  the `_name`:

```
class mom_ac(osv.osv):
    _inherit='mom.action'
    _columns = {
        'new_field':fields.char('Action'),
    }
```

And you should write your original model in the search view:

```
<record id="minutes_meeting_search_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">mom action search view</field>
    <field name="model">mom.action</field>
    <field eval="10" name="priority"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="MoM">
            <filter icon="terp-mail-message-new" string="Action Items" name="my_requests_filter" domain="[('Status','!=','Done')]" />
            <field name="act_ion"/>
            <field name="new_field"/>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Not actually, I do not want create or edit button at the top for a search view, so had used a different class i.e, mom.ac and had used it for search view.